# How to change the zoom centerpoint in an ILNumerics scene viewed with a camera

Tags: ilnumerics

I would like to be able to zoom into an ILNumerics scene viewed by a camera (as in scene.Camera) with the center point of the zoom determined by where the mouse pointer is located when I start spinning the mouse scroll wheel.  The default zoom behavior is for the zoom center to be at the scene.Camera.LookAt point.  So I guess this would require the mouse to be tracked in (X,Y) continuously and for that point to be used as the new LookAt point? This seems to be like [this post on getting the 3D coordinates from a mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676981/how-to-find-the-3d-coordinates-of-a-surface-from-the-click-location-of-the-mouse), but in my case there's no click to indicate the location of the mouse.

Tips would be greatly appreciated!

BTW, this kind of zoom method is standard operating procedure in CAD software to zoom in and out on an assembly of parts.  It's super convenient for the user.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just gone through *lots* of posts to try to find some guidance before I started flailing for hours with code.  Incidentally, I've found that the pan feature using the right mouse button doesn't seem to work with camera scenes (it does with plot cubes).  That would also work in a pinch, panning and then zooming, but can't do that without panning...

Comment: A common approach is to acquire the mouse coordinates to compute the intended zoom _direction_. Use this to compute a new transformation matrix for the camera. Rotation -> zoom -> backrotation - in _reversed_ order. This simply goes into the mouse scroll event and you should be done.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to overload the MouseWheel event handler. The current coordinates of the mouse are available here, too.

1. Use the mouse screen coordinates to acquire (to "pick") the world
   coordinate corresponding to the primitive under the mouse.
2. Adjust the `Camera.Position` and `Camera.ZoomFactor` to 'move' the camera closer to the point under the mouse and to achieve the required 'directional zoom' effect.

Here is a complete example from the [ILNumerics website](https://ilnumerics.net/examples.php?exid=241cfdf7284e7c21d9f86b39dc995d02):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ILNumerics; 
using ILNumerics.Drawing;
using ILNumerics.Drawing.Plotting;
using static ILNumerics.Globals;
using static ILNumerics.ILMath;

namespace ILNumerics.Examples.DirectionalZoom {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Array<float> X = 0, Y = 0, Z = CreateData(X, Y);
            var surface = new Surface(Z, X, Y, colormap: Colormaps.Winter);
            surface.UseLighting = true;
            surface.Wireframe.Visible = false; 
            panel2.Scene.Camera.Add(surface);

            // setup mouse handlers
            panel2.Scene.Camera.Projection = Projection.Orthographic;
            panel2.Scene.Camera.MouseDoubleClick += Camera_MouseDoubleClick;
            panel2.Scene.Camera.MouseWheel += Camera_MouseWheel;

            // initial zoom all
            ShowAll(panel2.Scene.Camera); 
        }

        private void Camera_MouseWheel(object sender, Drawing.MouseEventArgs e) {

            // Update: added comments. 

            // the next conditionals help to sort out some calls not needed. Helpful for performance.
            if (!e.DirectionUp) return;
            if (!(e.Target is Triangles)) return;

            // make sure to start with the SceneSyncRoot - the copy of the scene which receives 
            // user interaction and is eventually used for rendering. See: https://ilnumerics.net/scene-management.html 
            var cam = panel2.SceneSyncRoot.First<Camera>();

            if (Equals(cam, null)) return; // TODO: error handling. (Should not happen in regular setup, though.)

            // in case the user has configured limited interaction
            if (!cam.AllowZoom) return;
            if (!cam.AllowPan) return; // this kind of directional zoom "comprises" a pan operation, to some extent. 

            // find mouse coordinates. Works only if mouse is over a Triangles shape (surfaces, but not wireframes): 
            using (var pick = panel2.PickPrimitiveAt(e.Target as Drawable, e.Location)) {

                if (pick.NextVertex.IsEmpty) return;

                // acquire the target vertex coordinates (world coordinates) of the mouse
                Array<float> vert = pick.VerticesWorld[pick.NextVertex[0], r(0, 2), 0];
                // and transform them into a Vector3 for easier computations
                var vertVec = new Vector3(vert.GetValue(0), vert.GetValue(1), vert.GetValue(2));

                // perform zoom: we move the camera closer to the target
                float scale = Math.Sign(e.Delta) * (e.ShiftPressed ? 0.01f : 0.2f);  // adjust for faster / slower zoom
                var offs = (cam.Position - vertVec) * scale;  // direction on the line cam.Position -> target vertex
                cam.Position += offs;   // move the camera on that line
                cam.LookAt += offs;     // keep the camera orientation

                cam.ZoomFactor *= (1 + scale); 
                // TODO: consider adding: the lookat point now moved away from the center / the surface due to our zoom.
                // In order for better rotations it makes sense to place the lookat point back to the surface, 
                // by adjusting cam.LookAt appropriately. Otherwise, one could use cam.RotationCenter.

                e.Cancel = true; // don't execute common mouse wheel handlers
                e.Refresh = true; // immediate redraw at the end of event handling
            }
        }

        private void Camera_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, Drawing.MouseEventArgs e) {
            var cam = panel2.Scene.Camera; 
            ShowAll(cam);
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.Refresh = true; 
        }

        // Some sample data. Replace this with your own data! 
        private static RetArray<float> CreateData(OutArray<float> Xout, OutArray<float> Yout) {
            using (Scope.Enter()) {
                Array<float> x_ = linspace<float>(0, 20, 100);
                Array<float> y_ = linspace<float>(0, 18, 80);
                Array<float> Y = 1, X = meshgrid(x_, y_, Y);

                Array<float> Z = abs(sin(sin(X) + cos(Y))) + .01f * abs(sin(X * Y));
                if (!isnull(Xout)) {
                    Xout.a = X;
                }
                if (!isnull(Yout)) {
                    Yout.a = Y;
                }
                return -Z; 
            }
        }
        // See: https://ilnumerics.net/examples.php?exid=7b0b4173d8f0125186aaa19ee8e09d2d
        public static double ShowAll(Camera cam) {
            // Update: adjusts the camera Position too. 

            // this example works only with orthographic projection. You will need to take the view frustum 
            // into account, if you want to make this method work with perspective projection also. however, 
            // the general functioning would be similar....
            if (cam.Projection != Projection.Orthographic) {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            // get the overall extend of the cameras scene content
            var limits = cam.GetLimits();
            // take the maximum of width/ height
            var maxExt = limits.HeightF > limits.WidthF ? limits.HeightF : limits.WidthF;
            // make sure the camera looks at the unrotated bounding box
            cam.Reset();
            // center the camera view
            cam.LookAt = limits.CenterF;
            cam.Position = cam.LookAt + Vector3.UnitZ * 10; 
            // apply the zoom factor: the zoom factor will scale the 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'right' limits 
            // of the view. In order to fit exactly, we must take the "radius"
            cam.ZoomFactor = maxExt * .50;
            return cam.ZoomFactor;
        }

    }
}
```

Note, that the new handler performs the directional zoom only when the mouse is located over an object hold by this Camera! If, instead, the mouse is placed on the background of the scene or over some other Camera / plot cube object no effect will be visible and the common zoom feature is performed (zooming in/out to the look-at point).